# SSRS ReportViewer Server Report SubmittingParameterValues how to get name of the parameter being set?

Tags: reporting-services, event-handling

While working with SSRS reports, want to handle the event of SubmittingParameterValues. However, there is no clue on how to get the parameter being set.

Want to set other dependent parameter valid values based on the current parameter being set.

Is there any alternative way where I can intervene. This I need to do from ASP.Net Web page code behind.

Comment: is there a reason you cannot use the normal cascading parameters functionality and handle this directly in the report design? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-cascading-parameters-to-a-report-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2016

Comment: Normal cascading parameters are set, however, based on some additional conditions in the application need to change the valid values for the dependent parameter.